# Connecting to SAPDB using ODBC

Tags: odbc, maxdb

I'd like to access a SAPDB database using ODBC so I've installed the latest ODBC driver from http://www.sapdb.org/

I'm trying to create a connection using the following connection string: 
`DRIVER={SAP DB (Unicode)};SERVER=192.168.12.11;DATABASE=ADQ;UID=ADQTEST;PASSWORD=TESTABC;`

However I get the following error message:

> [SAP AG][SQLOD32 DLL][SAP DB] Invalid authorization specification;-4008 POS(1) Unknown user name/password combination

I'm fairly certain that the username/password I'm using is correct (we've verified multiple times).

I also don't think it's a general network problem since if I give it a non-existing database it actually complains about the "database not running". Only with the correct database I get the invalid authorization error.

I'd very much appreciate any hints anyone might be able to give me.

Best regards,
Thomas

Answer (score 1):

The ODBC attributes for user id and password are UID and PWD not UID and PASSWORD.

Comment: Thanks bohica for the hint! Unfortunately it didn't change anything, still got the same error with using PWD instead of PASSWORD. There must be something else that's wrong.

Comment: Well the attribute is PWD and the error suggests a wrong username or password. Have you changed the password recently? because there is apparently more to it than a simple dbmcli command to change them (not that I know SAP, just read it online). Why don't you create a proper DSN from the odbc administrator and check the username/password that way first - you can always delete it afterwards.